# Updating an input with the value of a href Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $r['price']; ?>" id="buyorderprice" value=""><?php echo $r['price']; ?></a>
```

and my non-working jquery:

```
$('a[href="buyorderprice"]').click(function(){
$('#sellprice').val($('#buyorderprice').attr('href'))

});
```

The price value is just a number which is working. Also, I don't want the page to reload when I click the button just update the sellprice input which is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sellprice" name="sellprice" value="<?php echo
$coinTicker->price($coin2[1] , 'sell'); ?>">
```

the cointicker is the default value of a random number

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
$("#buyorderprice").click(function() {
    $('#sellprice').val($('#buyorderprice').attr('href'));
});
```

... since `#buyorderprice` is the id.

To make it more workable, change the href to read `href="#"` and use value ...

```
<a href="#" id="buyorderprice" data-value="<?php echo $r['price']; ?>"><?php echo $r['price']; ?></a>
```

... then you don't have to be concerned about the default anchor functionality that will try to navigate to the price.  Then, this line would become ...

```
$('#sellprice').val($('#buyorderprice').data('value'))
```

Comment: Made some modifications that will help, I think.

Comment: <a>s don't have values, you can only fetch the data attribute, I'd consider this as not good practice, use real data-attributes instead for keeping maintain- and readability.

Comment: I'll fix.  Hang on one.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript / Vanilla JS, you can achieve it like this:

```
var a  = document.getElementById('buyorderprice');
a.addEventListener('click',setValueNow);

function setValueNow(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var b = document.getElementById('sellprice').value = document.getElementById('buyorderprice').getAttribute('href');
}
```

**[Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLk0zbLb/)**

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input is changed, but then your page is reloaded and you don't see what changed. So you need to stop the page from reloading when you click the button.

Here is the code to do that:

```
$("#buyorderprice").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sellprice').val($('#buyorderprice').attr('href'));
});
```

[jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLk0zbLb/4/)

Comment: You should explain how your answer solves the problem, not just dump some code on him. Also, you don't need `return false` if you use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I actually like this answer for it's simplicity, but @Barmar is correct there needs to be more description, and it leaves other **bad practice** issues in place.